# Problems combining tikz and storebox: Missing number, treated as zero. With animate, page shipped out with text `graphicx`,

Tags: tikz-pgf, errors, packages, animate

When I load both `tikz` and `storebox` and compile the following MWE, I get an error message `! Missing number, treated as zero.`.  When I additionally load `animate`, I get no error message, but a spurious page with the text `graphicx`.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{storebox}
%\usepackage{animate}
\listfiles
\begin{document}
Test
\end{document}
```

- When I compile the document above (`tikz` then `storebox`, no `animate`), I get the error message shown below, along with a two-page PDF document.
- When I include `animate`, I get no error message, but still a two-page PDF document.
- If I load `storebox`, then `tikz`, and no `animate`, result is normal.  If I leave out `tikz` of any combination, result is normal.  If I leave *any* of the three packages out of the sequence `storebox`-`animate`-`tikz`, result is normal.  There must be some strange 3-package issue going on; but they're all relatively new and not obscure...

The log:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.4-1.40.13 (TeX Live 2012) (format=pdflatex 2013.9.26)  30 OCT 2013 21:50
entering extended mode
 restricted \write18 enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**test
(./test.tex
LaTeX2e <2011/06/27>
Babel <v3.8m> and hyphenation patterns for english, dumylang, nohyphenation, ge
rman-x-2012-05-30, ngerman-x-2012-05-30, afrikaans, ancientgreek, ibycus, arabi
c, armenian, basque, bulgarian, catalan, pinyin, coptic, croatian, czech, danis
h, dutch, ukenglish, usenglishmax, esperanto, estonian, ethiopic, farsi, finnis
h, french, friulan, galician, german, ngerman, swissgerman, monogreek, greek, h
ungarian, icelandic, assamese, bengali, gujarati, hindi, kannada, malayalam, ma
rathi, oriya, panjabi, tamil, telugu, indonesian, interlingua, irish, italian, 
kurmanji, latin, latvian, lithuanian, mongolian, mongolianlmc, bokmal, nynorsk,
 piedmontese, polish, portuguese, romanian, romansh, russian, sanskrit, serbian
, serbianc, slovak, slovenian, spanish, swedish, turkish, turkmen, ukrainian, u
ppersorbian, welsh, loaded.
(/local/opt/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/standalone/standalone.cls
Document Class: standalone 2012/09/15 v1.1b Class to compile TeX sub-files stan
dalone
(/local/opt/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifluatex.sty
Package: ifluatex 2010/03/01 v1.3 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO)
Package ifluatex Info: LuaTeX not detected.
)
(/local/opt/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifpdf.sty
Package: ifpdf 2011/01/30 v2.3 Provides the ifpdf switch (HO)
Package ifpdf Info: pdfTeX in PDF mode is detected.
)
(/local/opt/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ifxetex/ifxetex.sty
Package: ifxetex 2010/09/12 v0.6 Provides ifxetex conditional
)
(/local/opt/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xkeyval/xkeyval.sty
Package: xkeyval 2012/10/14 v2.6b package option processing (HA)

(/local/opt/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkeyval.tex
\XKV@toks=\toks14
\XKV@tempa@toks=\toks15
\XKV@depth=\count79
File: xkeyval.tex 2012/10/14 v2.6b key=value parser (HA)

(/local/opt/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/keyval.tex)))
\sa@internal=\count80

(/local/opt/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/standalone/standalone.cfg
File: standalone.cfg 2012/09/15 v1.1b Default configuration file for 'standalon
e' class
)
(/local/opt/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/local/opt/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size12.clo
File: size12.clo 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count81
\c@section=\count82
\c@subsection=\count83
\c@subsubsection=\count84
\c@paragraph=\count85
\c@subparagraph=\count86
\c@figure=\count87
\c@table=\count88
\abovecaptionskip=\skip41
\belowcaptionskip=\skip42
\bibindent=\dimen102
)
\sa@box=\box26
)
(/local/opt/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz.sty
(/local/opt/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/basiclayer/pgf.sty
(/local/opt/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/pgfrcs.sty
(/local/opt/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil-common.te
x
\pgfutil@everybye=\toks16
)
(/local/opt/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil-latex.def
\pgfutil@abb=\box27
(/local/opt/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ms/everyshi.sty
Package: everyshi 2001/05/15 v3.00 EveryShipout Package (MS)
))
(/local/opt/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfrcs.code.tex
Package: pgfrcs 2010/10/25 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.24)
))
Package: pgf 2008/01/15 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.12)
(/local/opt/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcore.sty
(/local/opt/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphicx.sty
Package: graphicx 1999/02/16 v1.0f Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)

(/local/opt/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.sty
Package: graphics 2009/02/05 v1.0o Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)

(/local/opt/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/trig.sty
Package: trig 1999/03/16 v1.09 sin cos tan (DPC)
)
(/local/opt/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/graphics.cfg
File: graphics.cfg 2010/04/23 v1.9 graphics configuration of TeX Live
)
Package graphics Info: Driver file: pdftex.def on input line 91.

(/local/opt/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pdftex-def/pdftex.def
File: pdftex.def 2011/05/27 v0.06d Graphics/color for pdfTeX

(/local/opt/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/infwarerr.sty
Package: infwarerr 2010/04/08 v1.3 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
)
(/local/opt/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ltxcmds.sty
Package: ltxcmds 2011/11/09 v1.22 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
)
\Gread@gobject=\count89
))
\Gin@req@height=\dimen103
\Gin@req@width=\dimen104
)
(/local/opt/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys.sty
(/local/opt/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys.code.tex
Package: pgfsys 2010/06/30 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.37)
(/local/opt/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.code.tex
\pgfkeys@pathtoks=\toks17
\pgfkeys@temptoks=\toks18

(/local/opt/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeysfiltered.c
ode.tex
\pgfkeys@tmptoks=\toks19
))
\pgf@x=\dimen105
\pgf@y=\dimen106
\pgf@xa=\dimen107
\pgf@ya=\dimen108
\pgf@xb=\dimen109
\pgf@yb=\dimen110
\pgf@xc=\dimen111
\pgf@yc=\dimen112
\w@pgf@writea=\write3
\r@pgf@reada=\read1
\c@pgf@counta=\count90
\c@pgf@countb=\count91
\c@pgf@countc=\count92
\c@pgf@countd=\count93

(/local/opt/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgf.cfg
File: pgf.cfg 2008/05/14  (rcs-revision 1.7)
)
Package pgfsys Info: Driver file for pgf: pgfsys-pdftex.def on input line 900.

(/local/opt/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys-pdftex.d
ef
File: pgfsys-pdftex.def 2009/05/22  (rcs-revision 1.26)

(/local/opt/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys-common-p
df.def
File: pgfsys-common-pdf.def 2008/05/19  (rcs-revision 1.10)
)))
(/local/opt/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsyssoftpath.
code.tex
File: pgfsyssoftpath.code.tex 2008/07/18  (rcs-revision 1.7)
\pgfsyssoftpath@smallbuffer@items=\count94
\pgfsyssoftpath@bigbuffer@items=\count95
)
(/local/opt/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsysprotocol.
code.tex
File: pgfsysprotocol.code.tex 2006/10/16  (rcs-revision 1.4)
)) (/local/opt/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xcolor/xcolor.sty
Package: xcolor 2007/01/21 v2.11 LaTeX color extensions (UK)

(/local/opt/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/color.cfg
File: color.cfg 2007/01/18 v1.5 color configuration of teTeX/TeXLive
)
Package xcolor Info: Driver file: pdftex.def on input line 225.
Package xcolor Info: Model `cmy' substituted by `cmy0' on input line 1337.
Package xcolor Info: Model `hsb' substituted by `rgb' on input line 1341.
Package xcolor Info: Model `RGB' extended on input line 1353.
Package xcolor Info: Model `HTML' substituted by `rgb' on input line 1355.
Package xcolor Info: Model `Hsb' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1356.
Package xcolor Info: Model `tHsb' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1357.
Package xcolor Info: Model `HSB' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1358.
Package xcolor Info: Model `Gray' substituted by `gray' on input line 1359.
Package xcolor Info: Model `wave' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1360.
)
(/local/opt/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcore.code.tex
Package: pgfcore 2010/04/11 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.7)
(/local/opt/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmath.code.tex
(/local/opt/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathcalc.code.tex
(/local/opt/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathutil.code.tex)
(/local/opt/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathparser.code.tex
\pgfmath@dimen=\dimen113
\pgfmath@count=\count96
\pgfmath@box=\box28
\pgfmath@toks=\toks20
\pgfmath@stack@operand=\toks21
\pgfmath@stack@operation=\toks22
)
(/local/opt/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.code.
tex
(/local/opt/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.basic
.code.tex)
(/local/opt/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.trigo
nometric.code.tex)
(/local/opt/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.rando
m.code.tex)
(/local/opt/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.compa
rison.code.tex)
(/local/opt/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.base.
code.tex)
(/local/opt/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.round
.code.tex)
(/local/opt/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.misc.
code.tex)))
(/local/opt/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfloat.code.tex
\c@pgfmathroundto@lastzeros=\count97
))
(/local/opt/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepoints.co
de.tex
File: pgfcorepoints.code.tex 2010/04/09  (rcs-revision 1.20)
\pgf@picminx=\dimen114
\pgf@picmaxx=\dimen115
\pgf@picminy=\dimen116
\pgf@picmaxy=\dimen117
\pgf@pathminx=\dimen118
\pgf@pathmaxx=\dimen119
\pgf@pathminy=\dimen120
\pgf@pathmaxy=\dimen121
\pgf@xx=\dimen122
\pgf@xy=\dimen123
\pgf@yx=\dimen124
\pgf@yy=\dimen125
\pgf@zx=\dimen126
\pgf@zy=\dimen127
)
(/local/opt/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepathconst
ruct.code.tex
File: pgfcorepathconstruct.code.tex 2010/08/03  (rcs-revision 1.24)
\pgf@path@lastx=\dimen128
\pgf@path@lasty=\dimen129
)
(/local/opt/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepathusage
.code.tex
File: pgfcorepathusage.code.tex 2008/04/22  (rcs-revision 1.12)
\pgf@shorten@end@additional=\dimen130
\pgf@shorten@start@additional=\dimen131
)
(/local/opt/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorescopes.co
de.tex
File: pgfcorescopes.code.tex 2010/09/08  (rcs-revision 1.34)
\pgfpic=\box29
\pgf@hbox=\box30
\pgf@layerbox@main=\box31
\pgf@picture@serial@count=\count98
)
(/local/opt/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoregraphicst
ate.code.tex
File: pgfcoregraphicstate.code.tex 2008/04/22  (rcs-revision 1.9)
\pgflinewidth=\dimen132
)
(/local/opt/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoretransform
ations.code.tex
File: pgfcoretransformations.code.tex 2009/06/10  (rcs-revision 1.11)
\pgf@pt@x=\dimen133
\pgf@pt@y=\dimen134
\pgf@pt@temp=\dimen135
)
(/local/opt/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorequick.cod
e.tex
File: pgfcorequick.code.tex 2008/10/09  (rcs-revision 1.3)
)
(/local/opt/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreobjects.c
ode.tex
File: pgfcoreobjects.code.tex 2006/10/11  (rcs-revision 1.2)
)
(/local/opt/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepathproce
ssing.code.tex
File: pgfcorepathprocessing.code.tex 2008/10/09  (rcs-revision 1.8)
)
(/local/opt/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorearrows.co
de.tex
File: pgfcorearrows.code.tex 2008/04/23  (rcs-revision 1.11)
)
(/local/opt/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreshade.cod
e.tex
File: pgfcoreshade.code.tex 2008/11/23  (rcs-revision 1.13)
\pgf@max=\dimen136
\pgf@sys@shading@range@num=\count99
)
(/local/opt/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreimage.cod
e.tex
File: pgfcoreimage.code.tex 2010/03/25  (rcs-revision 1.16)

(/local/opt/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreexternal.
code.tex
File: pgfcoreexternal.code.tex 2010/09/01  (rcs-revision 1.17)
\pgfexternal@startupbox=\box32
))
(/local/opt/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorelayers.co
de.tex
File: pgfcorelayers.code.tex 2010/08/27  (rcs-revision 1.2)
)
(/local/opt/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoretranspare
ncy.code.tex
File: pgfcoretransparency.code.tex 2008/01/17  (rcs-revision 1.2)
)
(/local/opt/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepatterns.
code.tex
File: pgfcorepatterns.code.tex 2009/07/02  (rcs-revision 1.3)
)))
(/local/opt/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/modules/pgfmoduleshapes.cod
e.tex
File: pgfmoduleshapes.code.tex 2010/09/09  (rcs-revision 1.13)
\pgfnodeparttextbox=\box33
)
(/local/opt/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/modules/pgfmoduleplot.code.
tex
File: pgfmoduleplot.code.tex 2010/10/22  (rcs-revision 1.8)
)
(/local/opt/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/compatibility/pgfcomp-version
-0-65.sty
Package: pgfcomp-version-0-65 2007/07/03 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.7)
\pgf@nodesepstart=\dimen137
\pgf@nodesepend=\dimen138
)
(/local/opt/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/compatibility/pgfcomp-version
-1-18.sty
Package: pgfcomp-version-1-18 2007/07/23 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.1)
))
(/local/opt/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/pgffor.sty
(/local/opt/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.sty
(/local/opt/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.code.tex)
) (/local/opt/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgffor.code.tex
Package: pgffor 2010/03/23 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.18)
\pgffor@iter=\dimen139
\pgffor@skip=\dimen140
\pgffor@stack=\toks23
\pgffor@toks=\toks24
))
(/local/opt/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/tikz.cod
e.tex
Package: tikz 2010/10/13 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.76)

(/local/opt/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/libraries/pgflibraryplothan
dlers.code.tex
File: pgflibraryplothandlers.code.tex 2010/05/31 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.15)
\pgf@plot@mark@count=\count100
\pgfplotmarksize=\dimen141
)
\tikz@lastx=\dimen142
\tikz@lasty=\dimen143
\tikz@lastxsaved=\dimen144
\tikz@lastysaved=\dimen145
\tikzleveldistance=\dimen146
\tikzsiblingdistance=\dimen147
\tikz@figbox=\box34
\tikz@tempbox=\box35
\tikztreelevel=\count101
\tikznumberofchildren=\count102
\tikznumberofcurrentchild=\count103
\tikz@fig@count=\count104

(/local/opt/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/modules/pgfmodulematrix.cod
e.tex
File: pgfmodulematrix.code.tex 2010/08/24  (rcs-revision 1.4)
\pgfmatrixcurrentrow=\count105
\pgfmatrixcurrentcolumn=\count106
\pgf@matrix@numberofcolumns=\count107
)
\tikz@expandcount=\count108

(/local/opt/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/librarie
s/tikzlibrarytopaths.code.tex
File: tikzlibrarytopaths.code.tex 2008/06/17 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.2)
)))
(/local/opt/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/storebox/storebox.sty
Package: storebox 2011/12/21 v1.3a Store and reuse boxes in a file size efficie
nt way

(/local/opt/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/collectbox/collectbox.sty
Package: collectbox 2012/05/17 v0.4b Collect macro arguments as boxes
\collectedbox=\box36
))
(./test.aux)
\openout1 = `test.aux'.

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 6.
 ABD: EveryShipout initializing macros
(/local/opt/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/context/base/supp-pdf.mkii
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
\scratchcounter=\count109
\scratchdimen=\dimen148
\scratchbox=\box37
\nofMPsegments=\count110
\nofMParguments=\count111
\everyMPshowfont=\toks25
\MPscratchCnt=\count112
\MPscratchDim=\dimen149
\MPnumerator=\count113
\makeMPintoPDFobject=\count114
\everyMPtoPDFconversion=\toks26
) (/local/opt/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/pdftexcmds.sty
Package: pdftexcmds 2011/11/29 v0.20 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO
)
Package pdftexcmds Info: LuaTeX not detected.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdf@primitive is available.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdf@ifprimitive is available.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdfdraftmode found.
)
(/local/opt/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/epstopdf-base.sty
Package: epstopdf-base 2010/02/09 v2.5 Base part for package epstopdf

(/local/opt/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/grfext.sty
Package: grfext 2010/08/19 v1.1 Manage graphics extensions (HO)

(/local/opt/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/kvdefinekeys.sty
Package: kvdefinekeys 2011/04/07 v1.3 Define keys (HO)
))
(/local/opt/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/kvoptions.sty
Package: kvoptions 2011/06/30 v3.11 Key value format for package options (HO)

(/local/opt/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/kvsetkeys.sty
Package: kvsetkeys 2012/04/25 v1.16 Key value parser (HO)

(/local/opt/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/etexcmds.sty
Package: etexcmds 2011/02/16 v1.5 Avoid name clashes with e-TeX commands (HO)
Package etexcmds Info: Could not find \expanded.
(etexcmds)             That can mean that you are not using pdfTeX 1.50 or
(etexcmds)             that some package has redefined \expanded.
(etexcmds)             In the latter case, load this package earlier.
)))
Package grfext Info: Graphics extension search list:
(grfext)             [.png,.pdf,.jpg,.mps,.jpeg,.jbig2,.jb2,.PNG,.PDF,.JPG,.JPE
G,.JBIG2,.JB2,.eps]
(grfext)             \AppendGraphicsExtensions on input line 452.

(/local/opt/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/epstopdf-sys.cfg
File: epstopdf-sys.cfg 2010/07/13 v1.3 Configuration of (r)epstopdf for TeX Liv
e
))
(/local/opt/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/storebox/storebox-pgf.sty
Package: storebox-pgf 2011/12/21 v1.3a Patches for PGF to support transparency 
and shadings inside storeboxes
Package storebox-pgf Info: Patching macro \pgfsys@horishading.
Package storebox-pgf Info: Patching macro \pgfsys@vertshading.
Package storebox-pgf Info: Patching macro \pgfsys@radialshading.
Package storebox-pgf Info: Patching macro \pgfsys@functionalshading.
Package storebox-pgf Info: Patching macro \pgfsys@fadingfrombox.
Package storebox-pgf Info: Patching macro \pgfsys@transparencygroupfrombox.
)
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   <
l.6 \begin{document}

? 
! Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted).
<to be read again> 
                   <
l.6 \begin{document}

? 
! Extra \fi.
\document ...p <1sp\global \topskip 1sp\relax \fi 
                                                  \global \@maxdepth \maxdep...
l.6 \begin{document}

? 
[1

{/local/opt/texlive/2012/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}]
[2] (./test.aux)

 *File List*
standalone.cls    2012/09/15 v1.1b Class to compile TeX sub-files standalone
ifluatex.sty    2010/03/01 v1.3 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO)
   ifpdf.sty    2011/01/30 v2.3 Provides the ifpdf switch (HO)
 ifxetex.sty    2010/09/12 v0.6 Provides ifxetex conditional
 xkeyval.sty    2012/10/14 v2.6b package option processing (HA)
 xkeyval.tex    2012/10/14 v2.6b key=value parser (HA)
standalone.cfg    2012/09/15 v1.1b Default configuration file for 'standalone' 
class
 article.cls    2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
  size12.clo    2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
    tikz.sty    2010/10/13 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.76)
     pgf.sty    2008/01/15 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.12)
  pgfrcs.sty    2010/10/25 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.24)
everyshi.sty    2001/05/15 v3.00 EveryShipout Package (MS)
  pgfrcs.code.tex
 pgfcore.sty    2010/04/11 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.7)
graphicx.sty    1999/02/16 v1.0f Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
graphics.sty    2009/02/05 v1.0o Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
    trig.sty    1999/03/16 v1.09 sin cos tan (DPC)
graphics.cfg    2010/04/23 v1.9 graphics configuration of TeX Live
  pdftex.def    2011/05/27 v0.06d Graphics/color for pdfTeX
infwarerr.sty    2010/04/08 v1.3 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
 ltxcmds.sty    2011/11/09 v1.22 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
  pgfsys.sty    2010/06/30 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.37)
  pgfsys.code.tex
pgfsyssoftpath.code.tex    2008/07/18  (rcs-revision 1.7)
pgfsysprotocol.code.tex    2006/10/16  (rcs-revision 1.4)
  xcolor.sty    2007/01/21 v2.11 LaTeX color extensions (UK)
   color.cfg    2007/01/18 v1.5 color configuration of teTeX/TeXLive
 pgfcore.code.tex
pgfcomp-version-0-65.sty    2007/07/03 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.7)
pgfcomp-version-1-18.sty    2007/07/23 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.1)
  pgffor.sty    2010/03/23 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.18)
 pgfkeys.sty    
 pgfkeys.code.tex
  pgffor.code.tex
    tikz.code.tex
storebox.sty    2011/12/21 v1.3a Store and reuse boxes in a file size efficient
 way
collectbox.sty    2012/05/17 v0.4b Collect macro arguments as boxes
supp-pdf.mkii
pdftexcmds.sty    2011/11/29 v0.20 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO)
epstopdf-base.sty    2010/02/09 v2.5 Base part for package epstopdf
  grfext.sty    2010/08/19 v1.1 Manage graphics extensions (HO)
kvdefinekeys.sty    2011/04/07 v1.3 Define keys (HO)
kvoptions.sty    2011/06/30 v3.11 Key value format for package options (HO)
kvsetkeys.sty    2012/04/25 v1.16 Key value parser (HO)
etexcmds.sty    2011/02/16 v1.5 Avoid name clashes with e-TeX commands (HO)
epstopdf-sys.cfg    2010/07/13 v1.3 Configuration of (r)epstopdf for TeX Live
storebox-pgf.sty    2011/12/21 v1.3a Patches for PGF to support transparency an
d shadings inside storeboxes
 ***********

 ) 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 10228 strings out of 493481
 196958 string characters out of 3140986
 10231912 words of memory out of 10432467
 13337 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+200000
 3938 words of font info for 15 fonts, out of 3000000 for 9000
 957 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 56i,5n,56p,411b,111s stack positions out of 30000i,500n,10000p,200000b,80000s
</local/opt/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr12.pfb>
Output written on test.pdf (2 pages, 9563 bytes).
PDF statistics:
 18 PDF objects out of 1000 (max. 8388607)
 12 compressed objects within 1 object stream
 0 named destinations out of 1000 (max. 500000)
 13 words of extra memory for PDF output out of 10000 (max. 10000000)
```

I've used this combination of packages before.  What's going on, and how can I amend this problem or use a workaround?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a bug in `storebox.sty`:

```
\AtBeginDocument{%
    \@ifpackageloaded{pgf}{\RequirePackage{storebox-pgf}{}}%
}
```

should be

```
\AtBeginDocument{%
    \@ifpackageloaded{pgf}{\RequirePackage{storebox-pgf}}{}%
}
```

When TeX executes this piece of code, it looks for the third argument to `\@ifpackageloaded` and it finds `\ifnum` which comes just after `\@begindocumenthook` in the code for `\document`. So this `\ifnum` is gobbled because `pgf` is loaded by `tikz` and what happens is that TeX sees

```
\topskip>1sp
```

which is meaningless. Indeed the error is “Missing number, treated as zero” because `>` is out of place. After this one has the usual error “Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted)” and then “Extra `\fi`”.

This explains why you have no error when `tikz` is not loaded: `\@ifpackageloaded` will follow the false branch, thus reinserting the `\ifnum` it mistakenly took as the third argument to `\@ifpackageloaded`.

You can temporarily fix it by adding

```
\AtBeginDocument{{}}
```

just after `\usepackage{storebox}`, which will provide the required empty argument for `\@ifpackageloaded`.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}%{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{storebox}
\AtBeginDocument{{}}
\usepackage{animate}

\begin{document}
Test
\end{document}
```

Comment: In recent versions of LaTeX, which come with a more fine grained hook management system, one should use `\AtBeginDocument[storebox]{{}}` instead to ensure that the empty group is input at the correct position.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, use pkg [`xsavebox`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/xsavebox/xsavebox.pdf) to circumvent the `storebox` bug:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xsavebox}
%\usepackage{animate}

\begin{document}
Test,\xsbox{hello}{Hello!}
\thehello % shorthand for \xusebox{hello}
\end{document}
```