# storebox conflicting tcolorbox

Tags: tcolorbox

According to this topic [How to design a command inquiring internally required packages?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/119469/how-to-design-a-command-inquiring-internally-required-packages) I am getting in trouble with the package storebox.

Have a look at this MWE example.

compiling with pdflatex, everything fine...

```
this example works
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{storebox}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\begin{document}

test
\end{document}
```

compiling with pdflatex, everything fine, but storebox is disabled...

```
this example also works
\documentclass{article}


\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage[disable]{storebox}

\begin{document}
test

\end{document}
```

compiling this example, getting an error...

```
this example wont work
\documentclass{article}


\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{storebox}

\begin{document}

test
\end{document}
```

but the following is the desired one...

```
\makeatletter
\let\req@onefilewithoptions\@onefilewithoptions
\def\@onefilewithoptions#1[#2][#3]#4{%
  \req@push{#1.#4}%
  \req@onefilewithoptions{#1}[{#2}][{#3}]{#4}%
  \req@pop
}

\let\req@list\@empty
\let\req@item\relax
\let\req@top\relax
\newcounter{req@count}
\def\req@push#1{%
  % \typeout{*** [#1]}% debug
  \ifcase\value{req@count}%
    \@ifundefined{req@#1}{%the file, whose package dependencies 
      \global\expandafter
      \let\csname req@#1\endcsname\@empty
      \xdef\req@list{%
        \req@list
        \req@item{#1}%
      }%
    }{}%
    \xdef\req@top{#1}%
    \edef\req@tmp{%
      \noexpand\AtBeginDocument{%
        \noexpand\stepcounter{req@count}%
        \xdef\noexpand\req@top{#1}%
      }%
    }%
    \req@tmp
  \else
    \expandafter\ifx\csname req@\req@top\endcsname\@empty
      \expandafter\xdef\csname req@\req@top\endcsname{#1}%
    \else
      \edef\req@tmp{%
        \noexpand\in@{,#1,}{,\csname req@\req@top\endcsname,}%
      }%
      \req@tmp
      \ifin@
      \else
        \expandafter\xdef\csname req@\req@top\endcsname{%
          \csname req@\req@top\endcsname
          ,#1%
        }%
      \fi
    \fi
  \fi
  \stepcounter{req@count}%
}
\def\req@pop{%
  \addtocounter{req@count}{-1}%
  \ifcase\value{req@count}%
    \global\let\req@top\relax
    \AtBeginDocument{%
      \addtocounter{req@count}{-1}%
      \global\let\req@top\relax
    }%
  \fi
}

\def\req@process{%
  \typeout{Requirement list}%
  \typeout{================}%
  \let\req@item\req@process@item
  \req@list 
  \typeout{================}%
}
\def\req@process@item#1{%
  \typeout{* #1\req@info{#1}}%
  \expandafter\@for\expandafter\req@tmp
  \expandafter:\expandafter=\csname req@#1\endcsname\do{%
    \typeout{ \space> \req@tmp\req@info{\req@tmp}}%
  }%
}
\def\req@info#1{%
  \@ifundefined{ver@#1}{}{ [\@nameuse{ver@#1}]}%
}
\AtEndDocument{\req@process}%
\makeatother

% this example also wont work because there is content in the page which should not appear
\documentclass{article}


\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{storebox}

\begin{document}
test

\end{document}
```

At the one and only page I should read "test". But I can read "req@count-1test"

I like the code of generating the filelist, because I parse this file and include the resulting csv in reports (or I want to).

EDIT 1:

The problem egreg pointed out is the second one I determined during trying to find a solution for example 4. There is content in the first page of the pdf which should not be here.

I want to see "test" in the document but nothing else.
What I can see ist "req@count-1test" which seems to me strange...

Comment: Sorry but what's the problem loading putting `\usepackage{storebox}` before `\usepackage{tcolorbox}`? Why can't you do that? I assume it has something to do with the changes you want to make before (??) `\documentclass` but it isn't really clear.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Problems combining tikz and storebox: Missing number, treated as zero. With animate, page shipped out with text \`graphicx\`,](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/141520/problems-combining-tikz-and-storebox-missing-number-treated-as-zero-with-anim)

Comment: It's a bug I already pointed out in 2013. In the linked question I also suggest a temporary workaround.

Comment: @egreg this does not solve the problem, that content appear in the resulting pdf. I can compile the last example.  But I see more content than expected.

Comment: @cfr this referes to the example of egreg. The suggested solution works for example 3, but has no effect on example 4.

Comment: @egreg  Will you provide this solution as answer so I can confirm your solution and mark the question as solved.

Comment: I retracted my closing vote, since the workaround suggested for the other question is ineffective here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is a bug in `storebox` already described in [Problems combining tikz and storebox: Missing number, treated as zero. With animate, page shipped out with text `graphicx`,](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/141520/problems-combining-tikz-and-storebox-missing-number-treated-as-zero-with-anim)

However, due to the code you add at the beginning, the workaround suggested in my answer there is ineffective, because the empty group is inserted too late. Instead of `\ifdim`, the `\addtocounter` instruction from `\req@pop` is gobbled, causing the printing of its argument.

You can fix the bug in this case with

```
\def\req@pop{%
  \addtocounter{req@count}{-1}%
  \ifcase\value{req@count}%
    \global\let\req@top\relax
    \AtBeginDocument{%
      \relax\addtocounter{req@count}{-1}% <---- ADDED \relax
      \global\let\req@top\relax
    }%
  \fi
}
```

The `\relax` will do nothing special for other included files, but in the case of `storebox-pgf` it will provide the “missing token” that will be gobbled.