# storebox not working as expected since texlive 2020

Tags: texlive, hooks, texlive-2020, atbegshi, everypage

I have to include page-specific content multiple times per page (DM codes to be specific) in a LaTeX document. To that end I use a combination of `storebox` and `everypage` such that content is typeset once and referenced multiple times in the resulting PDF:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
 
\usepackage[pagestyles,extramarks]{titlesec}
\usepackage{everypage}
\usepackage{storebox}
\AtBeginDocument{{}} % due to https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/141540

\newpagestyle{mypagestyle}{%
    \sethead[%
    ][%
        \usestorebox{\mybox}%
    ][%
    ]{%
    }{%
        \usestorebox{\mybox}%
    }{%
    }%
    \setfoot[%
    ][%
        \usestorebox{\mybox}%
    ][%
    ]{%
    }{%
        \usestorebox{\mybox}%
    }{%
    }%
}

\pagestyle{mypagestyle}

\AddEverypageHook{\storebox{\mybox}{some page-specific stuff repeated multiple times on that page}}

\begin{document}

Page 1

\clearpage

Page 2

\end{document}
```

This works fine for any version prior to 2020. However, `texlive 2020` introduced native hooks, making the `everypage` package obsolete. Since that version, the approach above results in:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \pdfrefxform \mybox
```

Using the new hooks directly, i.e., `\AddToHook{shipout/before}{stuff}`, gives the same error. Using `xsavebox` instead of `storebox` would work fine, but `xsavebox` is way slower such that it is not an alternative.

Does anyone has an idea how to make `storebox` work with `texlive 2020`?

Comment: why do you use a page hook to store the box? Simply storing in the document looks much easier.

Comment: Use `\usepackage{everypage-1x}` instead. The used `shipout/background` hook to emulate `everypage` is too late for your code to have any effect (and is limited in a group scope). It would be the correct code for placing additional information on a page, but not for altering actual contents of the page box.

Comment: Also, with the new hook mechanism, you should use `\AtBeginDocument[storebox]{{}}` to fix the `storebox` bug, instead of just doing `\AtBeginDocument{{}}` after loading the package.

Comment: but if the package has a simple bug of missing {} and hasn't been fixed since 2011 you might think about asking it be declared unmaintained and fixing it on ctan,

Comment: @Skillmon: that works indeed. Question is now how to make it work in the future as usage of `everypage-1x` is discouraged. Is there an easy way to hook into early enough with the new hook mechanism?

Comment: well you are claiming that xsavebox work, and if this is true then no hook is needed and savebox should be fixed. So show a working example with xsavebox. (And better answer the question why you actually need an everypage hook here. In your example it doesn't make sense).

Comment: @UlrikeFischer please read my comments regarding `everypage-1x` above. If you want a working example with `xsavebox`, replace `storebox` by that (`savebox` was never mentioned by me here, although I know about the connection between both packages).
Why I need an `everypage` hook (or similar): it has to be done within a `pagestyle`. I cannot fire that macros by hand on every page. Please consider my example code in my original question for reference.

Comment: sorry I meant storebox to savebox, but why do you need to fire on every page? Why can't you store the box at the begin of the document? The main point of xform is to reuse boxes, it doesn't make much sense to use it for boxes that needs updates. Or alternatively why don't you fire it in the page style code?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer because it has to be redefined on every page, as you would know if you have read my initial question. The content is page-specific. I inlcude datamatrix codes (multiple per page) that are specific to each page. And for that reason I want it to be stored once and referenced multiple times.

Answer (score 4):

The following allows to store a new box on every page and to reuse it on various place in the footer or header. The pdf contains two xobjects, one for every page. Something similar is probably possible with `titlesec` but I don't know the package very well.

The patch of the internal storebox command is needed as it doesn't store the reference to the xform global. This and the \AtBeginDocument bug should be reported to the author.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{storebox}
\makeatletter
%make command global
\def\@storebox#1{%
    \begingroup
    \@collectboxto\collectedbox{%
        \storebox@immediate\pdfxform resources {\the\pdfpageresources}\collectedbox
        \endgroup\global\mathchardef#1=\pdflastxform
    }%
}
\makeatother
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\newcommand\mybox{} %allocate the name to avoid to overwrite an existing command.
\lhead{\storebox{\mybox}{some page-specific stuff repeated multiple times on that page\thepage/\leftmark}%
       \usestorebox{\mybox}}
\rfoot{\usestorebox{\mybox}}


\begin{document}
\section{abc}
Page 1

\clearpage
\section{cde}
Page 2

\end{document}
```

Comment: That's a very nice example. I don't know whether `fancyhdr` is an option for me. If we could port that to `titlesec`, it would be the solution. But ++

Comment: it is quite probably somehow possible with titlesec, but I'm not using it, It is not fully compatible with hyperref and difficult to debug.

Comment: I considered using `fancyhdr` but, at the moment, I don't see the flexibility of `titlesec` with respect to head/foot notes and odd/even pages. `fancyhdr` was, for me, always a bit "on top" ...

Comment: fancyhdr can handle odd/even pages without problems. I never had a pagestyle I couldn't implement with it.

Comment: I've opened a ticket for the `{}` bug: https://sourceforge.net/p/storebox/tickets/1/

Comment: For this, xsavebox could be used too. No patching needed ;)

Comment: @AlexG I know (and I would use it) but the OP claimed it is too slow ...

Comment: I've read this too. It amazes me, since the underlying mechanism --- XForm Object generation --- is the same.